# table doesn't get updated

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data into **returnlist** table and update the **material** table when i click the insert button. insertion works fine but the material table doesn't get updated.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $Item = $_POST['Item'];
    $Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
    $Location = $_POST['Location'];
    $ReDate = $_POST['ReDate'];

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO returnlist(Item,Quantity,Location,ReDate) VALUES ('$Item','$Quantity','$Location' ,'$ReDate')",$connection);
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE material SET Quantity=Quantity + '$Quantity' WHERE 'Item'='$Item'", $connection);
    }

?>
```

Comment: More clarity is needed. When you click the button, do you send your request over ajax?

Comment: Assuming that the query is correct, have you check `$item`'s value if it is really what you expect? Or at least tried the query in `phpmyadmin` *(if you are using it)* ?

Comment: One more thing, if you are using variables inside a string, use `"` rather than `'`, so that the variable's value is used rather than using it literally

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* . Either use mysqli or pdo. This has been repeated soo many times. Also never go live in production with this 'code'. It's amazing nobody is talking about the massive security vulnerabilities in the above code

Comment: You need to concatenate the data values with the Sql string values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this format

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE material SET `Quantity` = `Quantity` + '".$Quantity."' WHERE `Item` = '".$Item."'", $connection);
```

Comment: it works! thank you!

Comment: the you can accept my answer as well

Comment: Maybe advice OP not to use mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote from `item` and change it to backtick.

```
UPDATE material SET Quantity=Quantity + '$Quantity' WHERE 'Item'='$Item'
```

change to use backtick

```
"UPDATE material SET Quantity=Quantity + '$Quantity' WHERE `Item`='$Item'"
```

or remove it

```
"UPDATE material SET Quantity=Quantity + '$Quantity' WHERE Item='$Item'"
```

Comment: Maybe advice OP to use prepared statements